# Unmarshalling enum in go changes datatype

Tags: go

Consider the following example,

```
package example

type Color string

const (
    red Color = "red"
    blue      = "blue"
)
```

I also have a color attribute in my DynamoDB. When I unmarshall the DynamoDB output to Color type, if the color values in DDB is "Red" then my dataType is string. If it is blue, then my dataType is example.Color("blue")

But the same issue did not occur when I assign Color type to both the constants like below.

```
package example

type Color string

const (
    red Color = "red"
    blue Color     = "blue"
)
```

Why there is a difference?

Note: I totally understand that in the first case, I did not specify Color explicitly. Then in the first case shouldn't the type be of string? But I do get it as example.Color datatype.

Comment: Don't know about the DynamoDB part; but note that in your first example the constant `red` is of type `Color` and the constant `blue` is an _untyped string_. The "implicit repetition" of type (which you seem to rely on), happens only if you also omit the expression, i.e. _only if you omit `= "blue"`_ will `blue` be of type `Color`, but then it's value will also be that of the previous expression, i.e. `"red"`. Relying on the "implicit repetition" makes sense only if you are using `iota`. Basically for string constants you should always explicitly specify the type.

Answer (score 3):

the difference in behavior is due to the explicit declaration of the blue constant as Color type in the second example, whereas in the first example, blue is considered an untyped constant (of type string) because it was not explicitly typed during the declaration.

Comment: Then why the datatype of blue in first case is not string but example.Color?